# Closed form for $\sum_{j = 0}^k \frac{j}{(k-j)!}$

Tags: summation

Is there a closed form for

$$\sum_{j = 0}^k \frac{j}{(k-j)!}$$

for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The generating function is $-\frac{e^x}{(1 - x)^2}$.  Maybe there's some way to extract the coefficients.

Comment: What do you mean by generating function ? Is is that these are the coefficients of the power series corresponding to the function you gave?

Comment: Yes.  If you can find a nice expression for the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative of the generating function divided by $k!$ that would be your closed form.  Not sure if that approach will work or not though.  Sometimes extracting the coefficients is trickier, but it might work.

Comment: Are you sure about the function? I think it should be $\frac{xe^x}{(1-x)^2}$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, $\frac{x e^x}{(1 - x)^2}$.  I dropped the $x$ I multiplied it by and added a minus sign in my original comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reversing the order of the sum (i.e. replacing $j$ with $k-j$ everywhere) gives
$$
S_k = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{j}{(k-j)!} = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{k-j}{j!} = k\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} - \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{(j-1)!}.
$$
Now, using that $\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} = e \frac{\Gamma(k+1,1)}{\Gamma(k+1)}$ we recover
$$
S_k = e \frac{\Gamma(k+1,1) - \Gamma(k,1)}{\Gamma(k)}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

I did not find any closed form.

However, computing $$S_k=\sum_{j = 0}^k \frac{j}{(k-j)!}$$ for $(0 \leq k \leq 1000)$, it seems to be very close to $e(k-1)$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & S_k & S_k \approx & e(k-1) \\
 5 & \frac{87}{8} & 10.87500000 & 10.87312731 \\
 10 & \frac{8877691}{362880} & 24.46453649 & 24.46453646 \\
 15 & \frac{3317652307271}{87178291200} & 38.05594560 & 38.05594560 \\
 20 & \frac{42739099682215483}{827517689856000} & 51.64735474 & 51.64735474
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Maple gives ${\frac {1+ e(k-1) \Gamma  \left( 
k,1 \right) }{\Gamma  \left( k \right) }}
$

Comment: @Leox. Thank you ! Why don't you post an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Maple gives ${\frac {1+ e(k-1) \Gamma  \left( 
k,1 \right) }{\Gamma  \left( k \right) }}
$